# "sqldeveloper-18.1.0.095.1630-no-jre.zip" not found, aborting... error message

Tags: debian-installer, sqlserver

During installation of Debian package builder for Oracle SQL developer in Ubuntu 18.04, I used the following command:

```
make-sqldeveloper-package sqldeveloper-18.1.0.095.1630-no-jre.zip
```

but it is showing the result like this:

```
make-sqldeveloper-package 0.5.4 Copyright © 2009-2018 Lazarus Long
Debian package builder and installer for Oracle SQL Developer

"sqldeveloper-18.1.0.095.1630-no-jre.zip" not found, aborting...
```

Please provide the proper solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the command `make-sqldeveloper-package` is as follows:

```
make-sqldeveloper-package  -b <BUILD_LOCATION>  <LOCATION_OF_ZIP_FILE>
```

From [the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sqldeveloper-package/make-sqldeveloper-package.1.en.html):

> **`-b`** | **`--build-dir`** *<dir>*
>
>   base directory to build package

For example:

```
make-sqldeveloper-package -b /tmp/deb/ ~/Desktop/sqldeveloper-18.1.0.095.1630-no-jre.zip
```

In  this example `BUILD_LOCATION` is `tmp/deb`.

Comment: I got it @Goro ,but for clarification can you please specify the BUILD_LOCATION in  your answer,what does it mean?